# "Missing JavaFX application class application.Main" when combining JavaFX with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I am working on a JavaFX project that has to access encrypted Excel files. When trying to use `WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream inp, String password)` while the Stage is  shown, i get an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException`. So for testing i tried accessing an encrypted Excel file before showing the stage. But as a result i get a `Missing JavaFX application class application.Main` error. I can't even start debug mode.

I am using Windows 11, Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0), JDK Version: jdk-17.0.2

```
package application;
    
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScene.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String filePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\Sheet\\Excel_Sheet.xlsx";
        FileInputStream fis;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        String password = "test";
        
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(fis, password);
        } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: First remove all the JavaFX related code because it is probably not relevant for your problem and then show how you launched your program and the full stack trace.

Comment: Okay so I made Main not extend Application, deleted the start method, and removed `launch(args)` from the main method. This throws the error: `Fehler: Hauptklasse application.Main kann nicht initialisiert werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException`. Sorry it's in german, "Fehler" means error,"Hauptklasse" means main class, "kann nicht initialisiert werden" means could not be initialized, and "Ursache" means caused by.

Comment: The error tells that the class-loader cannot access class `org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException` at run-time. This class is contained in `poi-*.jar` of your `apache poi` version. In `poi-5.2.2.jar` for version 5.2.2 for example. If that error occurs, then the class-loader is not able to access this jar at run-time. It is hard to determine **why** this is the case as it is dependent of your environment settings, which we don't know.

Comment: In short, you're missing a dependency at run-time (but apparently not at compile-time, or you'd be getting a compilation error). Make sure the needed JAR files are placed on the class-path or module-path when executing your code. If you're using Maven or Gradle, which I recommend, then make sure to use the build tool for executing the code (i.e., have your IDE delegate to the build tool, instead of letting the IDE use its own built-in execution system).

Comment: Indeed the Apache POI library was placed in classpath, moving it to modulepath fixed the problem. Thank's a lot

Comment: That's why I said "show how you launched your program" because it obviously was a runtime error. You were lucky that @Slaw guessed it right.